# Casper PHP Extension - Errors during installation

Tags: php, composer-php, casperjs

Having problems trying to install the extension package for PHP Casper:

[Casper PHP extension](https://github.com/synackSA/casperjs-php/blob/master/README.md)

I have installed all the prerequisites:

1. PhantomJS
2. CasperJS
3. Casper PHP wrapper

I am just getting an error when installing the package using composer - and this script:

```
composer require synacksa/casperjs-php
```

The error I am getting when I try to install  from composer is this:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a version of package synacksa/casperjs-php matching your minimum-stability (stable). Require it with
   an explicit version constraint allowing its desired stability.


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Hi. As per [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.".

Comment: Thanks, edited the question and copied the text in from Composer

Answer (score 0):

This is because package (`synacksa/casperjs-php`) doesn't have a stable version (only `dev`).

Add the following keys to `composer.json` and then require the package:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

This will enable the installation of the non-stable packages. It will be enabled for all packages you want to install, but stable version will be preferred.

See [the `composer.json` schema](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) for details.

Alternatively, you can install package with:

```
composer require synacksa/casperjs-php:1.x@dev
```

This will change minimum stability only for this package.